# Create a system like "Edit Skills" option on linkedin

Tags: ios, iphone, linkedin-api

[image]
I want to create a system like linkedin. So that user can select a value from dropdown and it can be added to text box with a cross button and background box attached to it. So that user can delete the added skill before saving it

Is there any way to do this. Any kind of ideas is appreciately accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below library that might help you.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/amtaglistview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tltagscontrol

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gctaglist